# Code not considering decimals in calculation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I´m building a simple calculation app but under my test I notice that it will not consider the decimals in the calculation, only whole numbers.
I sort of miss something in the first bit of the calculation where:

```
NSString *ValueIn= self.ValueIn.text;
double value = [ValueIn doubleValue];
```

I have changed from "float" to "double" after reading some tips, but it´s not working as I hoped.

Any tips?

Comment: Try NSDecimalNumber first. And I think you should use another name for your variable, like NSString *mystring = [NSString stringWithFomat @"%f", self.ValueIn.text];

Comment: some typos in my code, but you should get the ideea. double MyDouble=[mystring doubleValue]; or NSDecimalNumber *myNumb and use decimalNumberWithString...

Comment: So where is it giving you an unexpected whole number?

Comment: What's the point of changing from float to double? What do you hope it to work?

Comment: Always name instance variables and methods starting with a lower case letter. Names starting with a capital are reserved for class names by convention. So "ValueIn" should be "valueIn" or better yet "valueString", so you can tell it's a string, not a numeric value. It also looks like you have a property ValueIn which is an textField, and a local variable ValueIn which is a string. That's a very bad idea. Avoid using the same variable name as both an instance variable/property name and a local variable at the same time. That road leads to serious problems.

Comment: If the string in your text field is something like "1.32" then your code should work as posted. You should probably add log statements that display the your string value and the value after converting it to a float/double. Make sure you use "%f" to display your double so you see it as a decimal value.

Comment: Thank you @DuncanC for pointing out my code should work. I have checked my code again, and I now see that it is working as it should when running in simulator, but not on my iPhone. I need to do some logging to see what is happening. Sorry for my "naming routine", I shall take your tip and be more consistently.

Comment: After some logging, and test I have found the problem is the decimal sign. My number pad on the phone is using "," but my calculator is expecting "." How can I set the correct decimal sign?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959917/uikeyboardtypedecimalpad-change-comma-to-dot). The problem was the locale settings using comma when the code expected a dot.