# Using NSNumberFormatter on user entered number from UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to localise my app so that when a user enters a number via a UITextField it gets formatted to the local currency (e.g. $1,024 for US and €1.024 for EU). This number is then used to calculate two fees and a breakeven point which are then displayed.

I've tried:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

costN = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: myTextField.text.floatValue];
gameN = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: cost * 0.10];
steamN = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: cost * 0.05];
breakevenNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: (costN.floatValue + gameN.floatValue + steamN.floatValue)];

breakevenS = [formatter stringFromNumber: breakevenNumber];
breakevenDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithString: breakevenString];

gameFeeS = [formatter stringFromNumber: gameN];
csgoFeesDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithString: gameFeeS];

steamFeeS = [formatter stringFromNumber: steamN];
steamFeesDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithString: steamFeeS];
```

and it works while the region in the simulator is set to Australia but if I set it to a European country (e.g. France) then the user-entered value never gets assigned to costN, instead costN's value is always 0.

**EDIT**
Managed to get it working, here is the code:

```
float cost = [[myTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"," withString: @"."] floatValue];
float game = cost * 0.10;
float steam = cost * 0.05;
float breakeven = cost + game + steam;

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
self.breakevenDisplay.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: breakeven]];
self.gameFeeCostLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: game]];
self.steamFeesDisplay.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: steam]];
```

Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8177795/2229069) in another thread.

Comment: Is costN's value really 0? because it looks to be assigned myTextField's value, and the number formatter is not involved.  Perhaps I misunderstand your problem, but you might edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: @Jerry Everything works as it should when the simulator region is set to Australia, . It is only when the simulator region is changed to a European country that costN's value becomes 0. Perhaps this has something to do with the change from '.' to ',' in the decimal keyboard.

Comment: Ah.  Maybe you could try a number formatter on myTextField to parse the input.

Comment: @Jerry I managed to get it working thanks to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959917/uikeyboardtypedecimalpad-change-comma-to-dot).

Comment: Good you found a simple solution.  Using a number formatter with appropriate locale to parse input field would probably be a general solution but require a little more programming.